# How to execute JavaScript after dropdown data is inserted via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, user-experience

I have a form that loads some of its Data dynamically via Ajax, where, apart of a lot of other stuff, I fill a dropdown list. When selecting an item it will load the corresponding data into a table.

That all works fine, but now I want to be able to, by default, load the data of the first element once the page loads.

But since the dropdown populates over Ajax, it is filled slightly after `$(document).ready()`, so that doesn't work.

One way it might work would be to just wait for a second or two, since then it should all be loaded, but that really isn't something I fancy doing.

Any idea how I could achieve that?

I already tried it with `onloadeddata="loadData($(this)[0].selectedOptions[0].value)"` on the select tag, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

**EDIT:**

And I don't want to execute this in the ajax success function as data might also be loaded in other ways. It should really be the dropdown field or something that watches the dropdown, that executes this.

Comment: Look at the documentation of the [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function, it provides a callback which will be executed as soon as the request was finished (successfull or failed)

Comment: so trigger the change event on the select to load the data

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) provides a callback for successful request.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'stackoverflow.com/api',
    type: 'GET',
    success : successMethod
})

function successMethod(){
    // foo
}
```

Once the request receives a response `successMethod` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

jquery ajax have a `success` function in which you can do such kind of functionality. To do so you can try:

```
success: function(response) {
    // fill the form value with 'response'
    $('#dropdown_id').val('any_value');  // this will set the dropdown to specific value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  ...
}).done(function(data) {
 // do something with your data in here
});
```